# WP Editor does not Initialize Correctly When Form Elements are Removed from the DOM

Tags: wp-editor

I am using js code to add and remove form elements and to initialize the wp_editor on the dynamically added textareas with js. The wp editor is initializing correctly when I am only adding elements with the "add" button. However, when I click "remove", the last wp editor does not fully initialize (top toolbar is missing). I recorded a short video of the problem: [WP Editor Not initializing Correctly](https://www.loom.com/share/0081907fe23142ed9d1d4000c34baa29).

Here is the code I am using to add and remove the elements:

```
function addNewStep() {
    //get all steps
    const steps = document.getElementsByClassName('step');
    const lastStep = steps[steps.length - 1];

    // get last step input fields
    const lastStepFields = lastStep.getElementsByClassName('form-field');
    const lastTextArea = lastStepFields[1];

    // remove wp editor from last textarea to be able to copy it
    if (typeof wp.editor != "undefined" && isShowWpEditor) {
        wp.editor.remove(lastTextArea.id);
    }

    //new table body wrapper
    const tbody_element = document.createElement('tbody');
    tbody_element.className = 'step';

    //create the new step
    let newStep = lastStep.cloneNode(true);
    table.appendChild(newStep);

    table.insertBefore(newStep, lastStep)

    // loop through last step fields to increment ids
    for (let i = 0, n = lastStepFields.length; i < n; i++) {
        const field = lastStepFields[i];
        // set the id and name attribute
        if (i == 0) {
            // some logic
        } else if (i == 1) {
            //reinitialize the wp editor that we removed before
            if (typeof wp.editor != "undefined" && isShowWpEditor) {
                wp.editor.initialize(field.id, {
                    tinymce: {
                        plugins: 'paste,lists,link,media,wordpress,wpeditimage,wpgallery,wpdialogs,wplink,textcolor,colorpicker',
                        toolbar1: 'bold italic underline strikethrough | blockquote bullist numlist | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify',
                        toolbar2: 'formatselect forecolor link unlink',
                        textarea_rows: 5
                    },
                    quicktags: true,
                    mediaButtons: true,

                });

                // increment textarea id
                newId = +(field.id.replace('id_', '')) + 1;
                field.id = 'id_' + newId;
                // create a new instance of the wp editor on the new textarea that we have just created dynamically
                wp.editor.initialize(field.id, {
                    tinymce: {
                        plugins: 'paste,lists,link,media,wordpress,wpeditimage,wpgallery,wpdialogs,wplink,textcolor,colorpicker',
                        toolbar1: 'bold italic underline strikethrough | blockquote bullist numlist | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify',
                        toolbar2: 'formatselect forecolor link unlink',
                        textarea_rows: 5
                    },
                    quicktags: true,
                    mediaButtons: true,

                });
            }

        }
    }

}

function removeStep() {
    const steps = document.getElementsByClassName('step');
    const lastStep = steps[steps.length - 1];
    lastStep.remove();
}

jQuery('#stg_steps').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addNewStep();
    counter++;
});

jQuery('#stg_remove_steps').click(function(e) {
    removeStep();
    counter--;
})
```

Everything is working, apart from the buggy wp editor initialization (toolbar is completely missing) when you have clicked the remove button beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the issue was. Apparently, when you remove the textarea element from the DOM, you also need to remove the `wp editor` that has been attached to it. (if you decide to re-add the textarea to the DOM later) I found out that even though the textarea is successfully removed, its id is still stored in the `tinyMCEPreInit` object and this causes problems with the dynamic `wp editor` initialization. Removing the `wp editor` with its corresponding textarea id fixed the issue for me:

```
function removeStep() {
    const steps = document.getElementsByClassName('step');
    const lastStep = steps[steps.length - 1];
    const lastTextArea = lastStep.getElementsByClassName('form-field')[1];
    lastStep.remove();
    if (typeof wp.editor != "undefined") {
        wp.editor.remove(lastTextArea.id);
    }
    counter--;
}
```